# If we're interested in adjoining more stuff to a model of set theory, what is the appropriate notion of "embedding"?

Tags: set-theory

I sometimes like to imagine that I have a model $V_0$ of set theory, not necessarily well-founded, to which we adjoin more stuff, like an inaccessible cardinal (together with the least number of sets that need to be added in order that the new model still satisfies ZFC). Denoting the new model $V_1$, what we basically get is some kind of embedding of $V_0$ into $V_1.$ However, it needn't be an *elementary* embedding - for example, $V_1$ might have an inaccessible cardinal while $V_0$ may lack one.

**Question 1.** What is the appropriate notion of "embedding" if we're interested in adjoining more stuff to a model of set theory?

That's my general question. Here's a more specific one.

Andres Caicedo gives a notion of embedding in his answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288185/is-the-appropriate-notion-of-homomorphism-between-models-of-set-theory-the-obvi), namely:

(Paraphrasing). Let $V_0$ and $V_1$ denote models of ZFC (membership relations $\in_0$ and $\in_1$ respectively). Then a function $f : V_0 \rightarrow V_1$ will be called an *embedding* iff

1. It is injective, and
2. For all $x_0,y_0 \in V$ we have $x_0 \in_0 y_0$ iff $f(x_0) \in_1 f(y_0).$

Also, we can make the definition more strict by replacing 2 with

2.' For all $y_0 \in V_0$ we have that $$f(\{x_0 \in V_0 \mid x_0 \in_0 y_0\}) = \{x_1 \in V_1 \mid x_1 \in_1 f(y_0)\}.$$

Without invoking any of the properties of membership, it is straightforward to show that in the presence of injectivity, condition 2 is <strike>equivalent to</strike> implied by 2'.

**Question 2.** Are either of these the correct notion of embedding when adjoining new elements?

Comment: I don't see that 2 and 2' are equivalent, even in the presence of injectivity. Suppose that $V_0\subset V_1$, that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in V_0$, that $\in_0$ is just the restriction to $V_0$ of $\in_1$, and that, for some $y\in V_0$ and $z\in V_1-V_0$, we have $z\in_1 y$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, thanks, you're totally right. I replaced "equivalent to" with "implied by" which I think is now correct.

Comment: Yes, "implied by" looks right.